# DNS cache poisoning & transaction ID

Tags: domain-name-system

I read many articles about it and I do not understand how the cache poisoning is possible if:

- the query is cancelled and marked as failure if the transaction ID of the response does not match (i.e. attackers cannot brute force the transaction ID since they will only the first response will get accepted)
- recursive resolver send only 1 request for the same domain/type/class at a time, meaning the attackers cannot trigger many request for the same domain to brute force the transaction ID

In that configuration that looks basic, how is cache poisoning possible if the attackers need to guess the transaction ID?
Will the attackers force the recursive resolver to resolve the same domain again and again to have more tries? In that case that could take hours...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's mainly your first bullet point that is inaccurate:

> - the query is cancelled and marked as failure if the transaction ID of
>   the response does not match (i.e. attackers cannot brute force the
>   transaction ID since they will only the first response will get
>   accepted)

When an unknown transaction id is received, that response is discarded.
But your assumption that the outstanding query is somehow considered failed is not true.

Effectively, this attack scenario becomes a race for the attacker to get a valid response in before the response from the real nameserver arrives.

The problem with your assumption is that the whole point of the transaction id (+ UDP source port) is to match the response to an outstanding query, but when there is a response where these values are wrong (doesn't match any query), how can you tell which query you should consider failed?
And if you were to allow some form of partial match, how would you implement that in a way that doesn't replace a somewhat burdensome race for the attacker with a trivially exploitable DoS attack instead?

Options for "real" protection:

- DNSSEC allows the query originator to validate the authenticity of the records in the response, which ensures that an attacker-generated response is not accepted for names in signed zones.
- For queries from some form of client/forwarder to a resolver server specifically, DoT and DoH also avoid the cache poisoning problem *for this particular "hop"* (DoT/DoH only secure a communications channel between two hosts, DNS resolutions tend to have multiple such "hops").
  (Even just querying over TCP improves the particular scenario in the question, but the cryptography-based solutions are obviously much broader in terms of what attacks they deal with.)

Comment: Your point with the exploitable DoS attack makes the first assumption wrong definitely. However, let's say DNSSEC is not used by the nameserver and the request is UDP. If we receive many transaction ID that does not match, we can assume the server is under attack right? what are the possible options in that case? how to trust any response?

Comment: @vinz One potential strategy that comes to mind is something like "if a high number of unknown responses are received from an IP, flag that IP to only use TCP (if possible to connect?) for some amount of time". But I don't know if any existing recursor implementation can do that, or if there is some problem with that idea (other than the obvious issue of some nameservers not listening on TCP, even though not doing so is very much frowned upon).

Comment: @vinz Generally, the randomized source port + transaction id (+query name) has made the actual attack effectively impractical for many years. Then there were the recent https://www.saddns.net/ findings, which (ab)uses underlying network stack behavior to make that situation worse.

Comment: Apparently at least [Knot-resolver](https://en.blog.nic.cz/2020/11/19/knot-resolver-is-not-sad-dns-resolver/) and [(soon) Powerdns-recursor](https://github.com/PowerDNS/pdns/pull/9744) implement "switch to TCP" strategies.

Comment: thank you I will check their strategies. Also, would it be acceptable to server stale cached answer for some time if we detect a potential attack ongoing?